# Multiple RequiredFieldValidators on page but they need to apply to different button clicks

Tags: asp.net, multiple-instances, requiredfieldvalidator

I'm working on a asp.net page and I have the following scenario:

I have 2 fields that have requiredfieldvalidators which need to "fire" their validation when button1 is clicked but NOT when button2 is clicked and another field which is validated by another requiredfieldvalidator with the opposite scenario. (requiredfieldvalidator for this field needs to "fire" when button2 is clicked but NOT when button1 is clicked.)  Any suggestions for the simplest solution would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Validation Group](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx).

Sample code here:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <h1>Group1</h1>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidationGroup="group1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ValidationGroup="group1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

        <br /><br />
        <h1>Group2</h1>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="TextBox3" ValidationGroup="group2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="TextBox4" ValidationGroup="group2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

        <br /><br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="group1" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="group2" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: I knew there would be a simple solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use validation groups. See the next article http://www.dotnet-guide.com/validationgroups.html.